# Subida de datos por CSV a Wordpress incompleta

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, csv

Estoy intentando subir más de 400 propiedades desde un archivo csv, cree un plugin básico que contiene una funcion que se activa por ajax la cual abre el archivo csv que contiene las propiedades como un array, lo recorro con un while y luego voy guardando los datos en variables para ir asignándoles usando la función wp_insert_post de wordpress, el problema es que siempre se queda pegado en la misma parte, no avanza mas de ahi, les dejo mi codigo para escuchar sugerencias de como mejorar la subida de propiedades, quizas conozcan alguna forma de hacerlo por lotes sin editar los archivos csv:

```
    if (($handle = fopen( ABSPATH . "csv/fotocasa-rent-Anuncios-A Coruña.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
        
        $index = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ";");
        $data = array_shift(fgetcsv($handle, 0, ";"));
        
     // Read the CSV file line by line
        while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 0, ";")) !== FALSE) :

            // Datos de la propiedad
            $property_ref = $data[0];
            $property_agent = $data[1];
            $property_phone = $data[2];
            $property_desc = $data[27];
            $property_type = $data[4];
            // Aqui faltan mas variables pero las quite para poder publicar en stacoverflow

            // Caracteristicas
            $property_features = array();

            // Creacion de titulo y url
            $property_slug = "propiedad/$property_type-en-$property_operation-en-$property_location";
            $property_title = "$property_type en $property_operation en $property_location";
            $property_title = ucwords($property_title);

            // Insertaremos el post en la base de datos
            $inserted_property = wp_insert_post([
                'post_name' => $property_slug,
                'post_title' => $property_title,
                'post_content' => $property_desc,
                'post_type' => 'properties',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'meta_input' => array(
                    'es_property_reference' => $property_ref,
                    'es_property_advertiser' => $property_agent,
                    'es_property_phone_number' => $property_phone,
                    'es_property_price' => $property_price,
                    'es_property_country' => 1032,
                    'es_property_province' => $property_province,
                    'es_property_address' => $property_location,
                    'es_postal_code' => $property_postcode,
                    'es_property_bedrooms' => $property_rooms,
                    'es_property_bathrooms' => $property_baths,
                    'es_property_area' => $property_m2
                )
            ]);

            // Importación de Etiquetas en propiedad
            wp_set_object_terms($inserted_property, $property_operation, 'es_category');
            wp_set_object_terms($inserted_property, $property_type, 'es_type');
            wp_set_object_terms($inserted_property, $property_province, 'es_location');
            wp_set_object_terms($inserted_property, $property_condition, 'es_status');
            wp_set_object_terms($inserted_property, $property_features, 'es_feature');

            // Importacion de imagenes
            require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/media.php' );
            require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
            require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

            // Imagenes
            $property_images = $data[31];
            $images = explode(' | ', $property_images);
            $images_ids = [];   

            // Las recorremos y subimos
            foreach($images as $img):           

                $images_ids[] = media_sideload_image($img, $inserted_property, null, 'id' );

            endforeach;

            // Insertamos imagen destacada
            set_post_thumbnail($inserted_property, $images_ids[0]);
        endwhile;
        fclose($handle);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hola. ¿Cuál es el error? ¿Revisaste el .csv en la parte donde falla para verificar que dicho archivo no es incorrecto?

Comment: Me sale request timeout a pesar de que coloque para que no bloquee la solicitud

Comment: La cuestion está en que estas subiendo "demasiada" información para que PHP lo soporte, te lo digo por experiencia propia en donde yo tuve que subir 1M de registros y PHP no me daba el ancho (del todo) así que le cargue esa logica a mi BD, haz intentado hacerlo?

Comment: No lo he probado, como seria?

Comment: Creo que es porque no soporta subir tanta información a la vez, te recomiendo hacer lo siguiente, lee con javascript el csv y extrae los datos, conviertelo en JSON y de esa forma envias por ajax una propiedad, cuando se complete envias la segunda, de esa forma puedes enviar hasta mil propiedades, solo que en vez de subirlas todas de un solo, lo haces una a una, solo tienes que esperar a que termine la operación para enviar otra.

Comment: Conviene que des más detalles sobre el contexto. Si se trata de un volcado de datos que no volverá a repetirse lo mejor sería hacerlo a un nivel más bajo, en la consola. Si es un proceso que vas a hacer con una determinada frecuencia, entonces convendría separar los registros por lotes e irlos cargando por parte. También en ese caso, puedes programar un script que se ejecute por consola y lanzarlo desde un cron por ejemplo.

Comment: Voy a probar con javascript a ver que tal, son 753 archivos, que se subiran uno a uno una vez

Comment: Cuando hablaba de *consola* me refería a hacerlo directamente en el servidor, no en el cliente (Javascript), donde la carga será más pesada. Tú puedes por ejemplo poner esos 753 archivos en una carpeta y escribir un pequeño script en bash que lea esos archivos y los inserte en la BD o donde sea. Esto, hecho a un bajo nivel (la consola del servidor) va a volar comparado con hacerlo en PHP o, peor aún, en Javascript. Mientras más intermediarios uses, más lentitud en este tipo de procesos aparentemente costosos.

Comment: Cuando hablo de un Script en Bash no me refiero a algo del otro mundo. Sería [algo como esto más o menos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8539153/5587982). Ese script de 4 líneas va a leer todos los  `.csv`  en la carpeta en que estés y los va a insertar en la base de datos. Todo eso se hará directamente, sin pasar por PHP, ni por Javascript ni por ningún otro intermediario.

Comment: Esta interesante, tendria que ver que secuencia sql usar para subir las propiedades

Comment: ok, primero que nada parece que el archivo si sube de tu local a donde estas moviendo el archivo ... el subirlo con ajax no nos dice nada, ya que el problema esta en el procesamiento con php.

Comment: el error es un clasico de ineficiencia del script php por que primero estas leyendo datos, luego parseando, para luego cargarlos a la base de datos eso es imposible de hacer como lo planteas...

Comment: la manera correcta y mas acertada seria validar si el archivo .CSV es compatible con la tabla de la base de dato y hacer un load data in file ...

Comment: cualquier otro metodo requerira recursos que no tienes y demorara la ejecucion tanto que obtendras puros time out

Answer (score 0):

Al final termine solucionando subiendo de poco los csv, configure para que se suban 500 y luego vuelva a llamarse la función para subir los siguientes 500, así sucesivamente, de esta manera se completa la subida